# How to execute Coroutine from external GameObject which has been destroyed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I want to start a Coroutine from another script. The Coroutine is inside of the PlayerControl-script and the EnemyControl-script holds the line that fires off the Coroutine. The problem is the Coroutine doesn’t get executed because the gameobject holding the EnemyControl-script gets destroyed.

Now my question is: How do you start a Coroutine even when the gameobject gets destroyed? I just ask because I heard that Coroutines stop working when the gameobject gets destroyed.

The EnemyControl-script that invokes the Coroutine:

```
int achieveResult2 = PlayerPrefsManager.GetAchievement("achieveFirstKill_Key");

        if (achieveResult2 == 0) {
            PlayerPrefsManager.SetAchievement ("achieveFirstKill_Key", 1);

            playerShip.GetComponent<PlayerControl>().achievements.Add("First Kill");
            playerShip.GetComponent<PlayerControl>().achieveCntr = playerShip.GetComponent<PlayerControl>().achievements.Count;

            StartCoroutine(ShowAchievements());
        }
```

The Coroutine inside of the PlayerControl-script:

```
public IEnumerator ShowAchievements () {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

    for (int i = 0; i < achieveCntr; i++) {

        achievementText.GetComponent<AchievementTxt> ().ShowAchieveText (achievements [i]);
        achievementText.GetComponent<AchievementTxt> ().achieveTxtTimerRunning = true;

        achievements.Remove(achievements [i]);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a method you call to the player which starts the Coroutine locally.

Than you can destroy the enemy object safely since it is not responsible for starting the Coroutine anymore:

**PlayerControl**

```
public void ShowAchievements()
{
    StartCoroutine (ShowAchievementsRoutine ());
}

private IEnumerator ShowAchievementsRoutine () 
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

    for (int i = 0; i < achieveCntr; i++) 
    {

        achievementText.GetComponent<AchievementTxt> ().ShowAchieveText (achievements [i]);
        achievementText.GetComponent<AchievementTxt> ().achieveTxtTimerRunning = true;

        achievements.Remove(achievements [i]);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    }
}
```

And call it as a normal method from the Enemy:

```
 playerShip.GetComponent<PlayerControl>().ShowAchievements();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this out ASAP.:)

Comment: Strange. Now I get this error message: "Coroutine couldn't be started because the game object 'PlayerGO' is inactive!" I tested it with this line "Debug.Log("Active? " + this.gameObject.activeInHierarchy);" and it says 'false'. I don't know why my game object is inactive. Any help, please?

Comment: Well that's not something solveable int he scope of this question. It is also not solveable with your provided code ... If you have a new question open a new one